# Why my cosine interpolation of a cube's face doesn't work?

Tags: geometry, 3d, interpolation

**NB please :** executable use cases are available at the end of this question. I begin this question by showing you the problems of my program, then I explain how the latter works, and finally I end up with these both executable use cases.

## What I want to do

I want to draw the bottom face of a cube. To do that, I interpolate between the 4 vertices of this face. I use two kinds of interpolation :

1. Linear
2. Cosine

*I know it's typically the aim of GPUs, but I wanted to implement it myself to learn and try the "deep" mechanisms of 3D rendering.*

## Results

Each point of the following both pictures are interpolated between the 4 vertices of the bottom face (except the 8 vertices of my cube).

### With linear interpolation

It's OK, no problem.

[image]

### With cosine interpolation

Error. As you can see, there is some weird problem : face's points are inclined towards left.

[image]

## How do I interpolate between 4 points ?

I test all the combinations of interpolation's weights and, if the sum of the weights equals 1, I draw the resulting point. *I know this method is not very good (a lot of consumption of CPU and RAM), and there are `P` duplicates. But this problem is (1) secondary and (2) out of the range of this StackOverflow question.*

In other words : the definition of the interpolation between 4 points is : `P = aA + bB + cC + dD`. `a + b + c + d` must equals 1 to draw `P`, otherwise it's not drawn. `(a;b;c;d) \in [0;1]^4` by the way.

A concrete example is (step = 1) :

`P = 0a + 0b + 0c + 0d` is NOT drawn

`P = 0a + 0b + 0c + 1d` is drawn

`P = 0a + 0b + 1c + 0d` is drawn

`P = 0a + 0b + 1c + 1d` is NOT drawn

etc. ("I test all the combinations"). (Last is : `P = 1a + 1b + 1c + 1d`, which is not drawn).

To test all these combinations, I iterates on the weights, with a step, using recursion.

### Case of the linear interpolation

The above definition doesn't change : `P = aA + bB + cC + dD`.

### Case of the cosine interpolation

The above definition does change : `P = aA + bB + cC + dD` becomes `P = a'A + b'B + c'C + d'D`, with : `a' = 0.5(1 - cos(a * \pi))` and the idea is the same for the three other weights.

*This new definition is not random, I could explain how I found it, but it's out of the range of this topic (in résumé : a simple remap of the cosine function).*

## Question

Why does it works well with the linear interpolation, and not the cosine one ? Indeed, the cosine face's points are inclined towards left.

## By the way : interpolations between two points work well

Linear and cosine interpolations both work very well when used between two points, as you can see below.

### Linear interpolation

It's OK, no problem.

[image]

### Cosine interpolation

It's OK, no problem.

[image]

## Implementation and Executable

I wrote the program in Scala. First I show you the functions, then two use cases you can execute along with the given functions.

### Tests all the combinations of interpolations between `n` points of `k` coordinates

```
def computeAllPossibleInterpolatedPoints(step : Double, points : Seq[Seq[Double]], transform: (Double) => Double) : Seq[Seq[Double]] = {
  var returned_object : Seq[Seq[Double]] = Seq.empty[Seq[Double]]
  recursiveInterpolation(0, Seq.empty[Double])

  def recursiveInterpolation(current_weight_id : Int, building_weights : Seq[Double]) : Unit = {

    (.0 to 1.0 by step).foreach(current_step => {
      if (current_weight_id < points.size - 1) {
        recursiveInterpolation(current_weight_id + 1, building_weights :+ current_step)
      } else {
        val found_solution = (building_weights :+ current_step).map(transform)
        if(BigDecimal(found_solution.sum).setScale(5, BigDecimal.RoundingMode.HALF_UP).toDouble == 1.0) {
          returned_object = returned_object :+ interpolation(found_solution, points)
        }
      }
    })
  }

  returned_object
}
```

### Interpolates between `n` points of `k` coordinates

```
def interpolation(weights: Seq[Double], points: Seq[Seq[Double]], transform: (Double) => Double = null) : Seq[Double] = {
  var transformed_weights = weights
  if(transform != null) {
    transformed_weights = weights.map(transform)
  }
  if(BigDecimal(transformed_weights.sum).setScale(5, BigDecimal.RoundingMode.HALF_UP).toDouble != 1.0) {
    println("ERROR : `SUM(weights) != 1`. Returning `null`.")
    return null
  }
  if(transformed_weights.exists(weight => BigDecimal(weight).setScale(5, BigDecimal.RoundingMode.HALF_UP).toDouble < 0)
    ||
    transformed_weights.exists(weight => BigDecimal(weight).setScale(5, BigDecimal.RoundingMode.HALF_UP).toDouble > 1)) {
    println("ERROR : `EXISTS(weight) / weight < -1 OR weight > 1`. Returning `null`.")
    return null
  }

  transformed_weights.zip(points).map(
    weight_point => weight_point._2.map(coordinate => weight_point._1 * coordinate)
  ).reduce((point_a : Seq[Double], point_b : Seq[Double]) => point_a.zip(point_b).map(coordinate_points => coordinate_points._1 + coordinate_points._2))
}
```

### Interpolation functions

```
def linear(weight : Double) : Double = {
  weight
}

def cosine(weight : Double) : Double = {
  (1 - Math.cos(weight * Math.PI)) * 0.5
}
```

### Two use cases : between 2 points, each made of 2 coordinates (first use case : linear interpolation, second use case : cosine interpolation)

Note that you can add 2 new points to each of the following functions, to interpolate a face instead of a segment (for now, the below code indeed interpolates points of a segment).

```
val interpolated_points : Seq[Seq[Int]] = interpolator.computeAllPossibleInterpolatedPoints(0.05, Seq(Seq(22, 22), Seq(33, 33)), interpolator.linear).map(_.map(_.intValue()))

val interpolated_points : Seq[Seq[Int]] = interpolator.computeAllPossibleInterpolatedPoints(0.05, Seq(Seq(22, 22), Seq(33, 33)), interpolator.cosine).map(_.map(_.intValue()))
```

Comment: Not sure if this suits this cite (and not stackoverflow), but I definitely love the pictures.

Comment: Ahah thank you:)!

Comment: I think it can be an aliasing problem. It happens when sampling periodic functions.

Comment: Maybe this aliasing would occurs for linear interpolation between 2 and 4 points, and for cosine interpolation for 2 points. However, these 3 cases work well :/ In other words : why aliasing would only concern cosine interpolation between 4 points ?

Comment: I haven't read your implementation yet, but why do you draw $P = 0a + 0b + 0c + 0d$? According to your explanation, you should only draw points if the sum of weights is 1, but this point has weight sum 0.

Comment: Oops, it's a mistake. I am editing my question. This point is obviously not drawn. In particular, I confirm you my program doesn't draw it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I only remember after struggling to read through code, but I'd recommend posting pseudo-code rather than code here. Regardless, I tried to understand your implementation, and as far as I can tell, you test weights $a,b,c,d$ such that they sum to 1, and for these $a+b+c+d=1$ you directly plug them into your cosine interpolation to compute $a',b',c',d'$. In general, this will not give you a point in the face because you actually want the constraint $a'+b'+c'+d'=1$ to perform an interpolation.

Now, why does this work with a segment interpolation and not a face interpolation? The tl;dr is that $a+b=1$ will ensure $a'+b'=1$.
Indeed $$\cos(a\pi)=\cos(\pi-b\pi)=-\cos(-b\pi)=-\cos(b\pi)$$
and this yields
$$a'+b' = \frac 12(1-\cos(a\pi)) +\frac 12(1-\cos(b\pi))=1$$
When you have more coefficients however, this is unlikely to hold, so your interpolation is not really an interpolation.

---

To solve this, you can use the "transform" (linear or cosine functions) before testing the validity of the weights.

Comment: Indeed I didn't post pseudo-code but I precisely explained, in natural language, how works my program and I even gave an example: I think it allows to understand the implementation. But I can be wrong and next time I will give pseudo-code moreover. If I use `transform` before the test, all my points have a `SUM(weights) != 1`. Indeed, I wrote : `val transformed_weights = weights.map(transform)` at the first line of the function `interpolation` and I updated both `if` by replacing `weights` with `transformed_weights`. Same for `zip`, which has became : `transformed_weights.zip(points).map(...`.

Comment: @JarsOfJam-Scheduler Let me rephrase my remark, it would help if your code included more comments about what you are computing. Your natural language explanation was very helpful, and it is relevant to post the actual code, but on average I'd say people here are more interested in the concepts and maths, than code. So detailed pseudo-code explaining what is computed, and in what order, is simpler to understand. Once we have figured out there are no conceptual mistakes, it is then an implementation problem. Some people prefer to help on concepts, other on implementation, so it is good to be ...

Comment: ...able to figure out which is which quickly. Now regarding how to correct your implementation, I suggested to use `transform` earlier in your code, but that implies you have to change more than just putting `transform` before testing your weights. If I was doing the implementation, I'd store the transformed weights, check they are valid, and then perform a "plain" interpolation using these valid weights. I don't understand the last couple lines of `interpolation`, but I'd get rid of `map(transform)` or change it to `map(linear)`. In `computeAllPossibleInterpolatedPoints` I'd put ...

Comment: ... `building_weights :+ transform(current_step)` each time you sample a new weight.

Comment: Ooops, you are right. I didn't remember I wrote this `if` : `if(BigDecimal(found_solution.sum).setScale(5, BigDecimal.RoundingMode.HALF_UP).toDouble == 1.0)` in the function `recursiveInterpolation` which is located in `computeAllPossibleInterpolatedPoints`. That's why your answer didn't seem to be correct. I have edited my code. Here is the resulting cube's face, with cosinus interpolation. Do you think it's good ? There are not a lot of drawn points however, and I think it's weird no ?  https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZO2wC.png

Comment: NB : perhaps you could think some points' Y is greater than the others' one. But it's just an inacurracy due to computation and perspective projection. Indeed here you can see that they have the same Y, more or less (***I have translated the cube towards top, to align the bottom face with the camera***) : https://imgur.com/a/dm3xYQg .

Comment: @JarsOfJam-Scheduler That is indeed weird. It would help if you updated your code, because I cannot know if what you actually implemented is what I have in mind, or something else. Also after thinking a bit, what do you want to achieve with your cosine interpolation. Do you just want to obtain a particular distribution on each coordinates? Because in that case, this sampling method will probably not work.

Comment: I've just updated the code in my question. Don't hesitate to ask me something if need be. I want to use cosine interpolation instead of linear one to see if (1) it's usable to draw a face i.e. to interpolate between 4 vertices and to see if (2) it differs (applied to 4 points) a lot from linear interpolation (applied to 4 points) and, if it's the case, in what extent. As you can see, I haven't actually "important" reason to use cosine interpolation, it's rather a test than anything else in a personal project.

Comment: @JarsOfJam-Scheduler I haven't fully read your update, but I tested an implementation of my own in another language. I obtained mostly the same result, and this is where I wish I had more programming experience. From what I observed, the main issue stems from testing the sum of indices being equal to `1.0`. As a rule of thumb, you don't want to test equality with floating point arithmetic, especially when sampling something. Due to rounding errors in floating point arithmetic, two floats/double are rarely really equal to one another. It depends on the implementation, but ...

Comment: ... you should still avoid those. In my test implementation, when I tried a more sensible test (something like `abs( sum - 1.0 )< 0.01`) I obtained a more sensible sampling. If the margin is too small, the sum is only equal to 1 when $a+b=1$ with $c=d=0$, so you end up with only points interpolated between two points. As a side note, it's fine to explore things for yourself, I just asked because if it was for a more specific purpose, it's helpful to know that purpose to know what kind of answer is appropriate.

Comment: Indeed ! With `sum of weights < 0.1`, maybe there are a lot of uncorrect interpolated points ("uncorrect" = `sum of weights != 1`), as you can see I think there are too many drawn points that it should : https://imgur.com/rHeD1wU. With `0.05`, I think I got a more correct interpolated face : https://imgur.com/a/IJ0Cv56. Finally, with your `0.01`, I obtained : https://imgur.com/a/GAU4JWq. Is there any statistical (or other) way to determine the best margin (without empirical tests as I did), to keep a great proportion of correct interpolations and a very little uncorrect interpolations ?...

Comment: ... By the way, among these 3 results, which one would be the best according to you ? By curiosity, what are the geometrical criterias to determine if a point is really interpolated between the 4 vertices when using cosine interpolation ?

Comment: @JarsOfJam-Scheduler To be perfectly honest, this "cosine" interpolation doesn't make sense to me. The closest thing I'm aware of that is called cosine interpolation, would be how to interpolate a monovariate function between two data points. The way I've guided you here leads to a form of linear interpolation with a skewed selection/rejection criteria. It can be useful to attain certain density distribution, but then the proper way to achieve those is to start from the desired distribution, and work out a proper sampling method. Since I cannot identify the theory behind what you want to ...

Comment: ... do, I can't tell you what the "best" or standard way to do it, is. In 3D, the criteria to identify an interpolated point, depends on what you call an interpolated point. The face of a cube can always be seen as the convex hull of its four corners, which actually coincides with the linear interpolation of these corners. So checking a point belongs to the face is easy. If you change what it means to be a face, then the way to obtain point on that face (interpolate them) also changes.

Comment: Do you mean cosine interpolation can only be used/useful to interpolate between 2 points, and not between 4 points ? If it's the case : why ? After all, cosine interpolating a face (thus between 4 points) can be done (I did it), we really get a face : so why shouldn't it be used in this case ? I actually don't understand why we have created a linear interpolation "with a skewed selection/rejection criteria", since we use cosine. Note than even with the linear interpolation, this "selection/rejection" criteria (if I well understood, the margin condition `abs(sum(weights) - 1) <0.01`) is present

Comment: ... by definition of an interpolation, whatever its type is. (linear, bilinear, cosine, cubic, .. , interpolations always has its sum(weights) = 1)

Comment: @JarsOfJam-Scheduler From the moment you have sum of weights equal to $\sum_iw_i=1$, and pick the point $P=\sum_iw_ip_i$, you have what is in general called an [affine combination](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Affine_combination) of the $p_i$'s with weights $w_i$'s. When it comes to interpolation, that is called a linear interpolation, regardless of how you choose the weights. Other forms of interpolations are distinct from the linear, because you do not pick the point $P=\sum_iw_ip_i$, but something else. The standard monovariate cosine interpolation in 2D performs a linear interpolation ...

Comment: ... on the $x$-coordinate, but a "skewed" interpolation in the $y$-coordinate, resulting in a point that **cannot** be expressed as $w_1p_1+(1-w_1)p_2$. In fact, every point of the form $\sum_iw_ip_i$ with $\sum_iw_i=1$ belongs to the convex hull of the $p_i$. Other forms of interpolation usually try to not restrict themselves to that convex hull, to obtain other desirable properties (like smoother transition between the various interpolated faces). So what you did, is mostly only changing the probability/density that a particular point will be picked by your algorithm.

Comment: @JarsOfJam-Scheduler In this [link](http://paulbourke.net/miscellaneous/interpolation/), you can see several different interpolation methods for a **curve**, based on the same data points. Interpolating a **surface** is a lot more annoying. You can see some example [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interpolation#In_higher_dimensions), where you interpolate the color (in general the height). For a more geometric point of view, interpolating between sample points of a shape is related to a difficult problem called **surface reconstruction**.

Comment: Omg, thank you very very much for these explanations again, @N. Bach. You took a lot of your spare time to help me, and to write very detailed answers. It was a very great pleasure to speak with someone who is as passionate as you !  :)

Comment: Ooops, @N. Bach, I showed my results to some friends, one decided to use himself a cosine interpolation. He got this face : https://imgur.com/a/SUFaJ7I which is very different than mine ( https://imgur.com/L1xIfu6 ). I'm not sure he has the same definition of cosine interpolation than me. Do you think his result is more correct (have you ever seen such a result ?)

Comment: @JarsOfJam-Scheduler If you compare the implementation and underlying concepts, you should be able to figure out where the difference comes from. Your friend's result is closer to what I'd intuitively call a "cosine(?) sampling". If you perform an [inverse transform sampling](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inverse_transform_sampling) for each coordinate, and where the inverse cdf is a cosine, you should obtain a higher density at the corners (the original points), and lower density in the center (far from the points). If you perform a "step" sampling, then you will also obtain a grid.